# hide/show recyclerview: how to reset layout params when making visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In Recylerview: I am trying to hide and show a view

For hiding i am doing:

```
     vh0.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     vh0.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

But when i have to show back I am trying

```
    vh0.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                    
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpr = new 
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpr.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    vh0.itemView.setLayoutParams(lpr);
```

It does not show the save way as the below cardview.

My cardview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvsearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsuggest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Other Suggested Words" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**SOLVED: Mistake i Was doing:**
I didnt added:

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lpr = new 
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpr.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    vh0.itemView.setLayoutParams(lpr);
```

I was trying only:

```
vh0.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The above was not working because previously i did

```
vh0.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
vh0.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

So the margins are removed even I make VISIBLE its not shown.

Comment: Can you post the two different screenshots about what is happening before and after, it is quite hard to understand the problem by just looking at this code.

Comment: Edited my question and also found the answer